# DeleteMessage Action - Invalid Receipt Handle

Tags: amazon-sqs

Task is to receive messages and delete messages. Am modeling this in Postman. I can successfully execute the receive messages action, but not the delete message action.

I have tried copying the receipt handle string from the receive messages response and using it in the delete messages request, and also tried url encoding the string. Both returned errors

In Postman I run the aws sqs ReceiveMessage action and get the ReceiptHandle

```
<ReceiptHandle>AQEBjiliZegyBS/ZO9wta+a/heA/tSx/f6tLFqfH38jEZ2r9zguHAljXhG/B8tXaM+S6MKs/XGyZ206S3NC2V38CUKLO+sPF0mfP47wqu7+nAIwettlxTGQAYuCFqI1CYBYHXxgajB1UEiFz8Kc6v8SlWs/VPLX+IWjckoQOtMRl977sxM5pCLhMNvIwh1RYFvybM0D0WEbJEuYb9JU3DZuRZg/K5rjvNooPqER4FR1JJxpZiJ0tu6481CyePLtEh/J4+Yd2kYRyuqN788oEdSTZIKprA6lHUCiCmeuqCb0yEDsxJcCVX4GmDok5KMHm/E2bgjpRjVRxZ+mrnLqTSwojt0LXg61vv8dNF8QD4sngPXqhmKQ7yp5O6S8ygn4lIPaUGOl5cgX1HsB3Q9Pfv3sg4A==</ReceiptHandle>
```

Then I run the aws sqs DeleteMessage action

Try #1

Pass the ReceiptHandle with exact copy

```
Action=DeleteMessage&ReceiptHandle=AQEBjiliZegyBS/ZO9wta+a/heA/tSx/f6tLFqfH38jEZ2r9zguHAljXhG/B8tXaM+S6MKs/XGyZ206S3NC2V38CUKLO+sPF0mfP47wqu7+nAIwettlxTGQAYuCFqI1CYBYHXxgajB1UEiFz8Kc6v8SlWs/VPLX+IWjckoQOtMRl977sxM5pCLhMNvIwh1RYFvybM0D0WEbJEuYb9JU3DZuRZg/K5rjvNooPqER4FR1JJxpZiJ0tu6481CyePLtEh/J4+Yd2kYRyuqN788oEdSTZIKprA6lHUCiCmeuqCb0yEDsxJcCVX4GmDok5KMHm/E2bgjpRjVRxZ+mrnLqTSwojt0LXg61vv8dNF8QD4sngPXqhmKQ7yp5O6S8ygn4lIPaUGOl5cgX1HsB3Q9Pfv3sg4A==&Version=2012-11-05
```

In the response, Postman shows the ‘+’ being replaced with spaces, so assume this is an encoding problem:

```
The input receipt handle &quot;AQEBjiliZegyBS/ZO9wta a/heA/tSx/f6tLFqfH38jEZ2r9zguHAljXhG/B8tXaM S6MKs/XGyZ206S3NC2V38CUKLO sPF0mfP47wqu7 nAIwettlxTGQAYuCFqI1CYBYHXxgajB1UEiFz8Kc6v8SlWs/VPLX IWjckoQOtMRl977sxM5pCLhMNvIwh1RYFvybM0D0WEbJEuYb9JU3DZuRZg/K5rjvNooPqER4FR1JJxpZiJ0tu6481CyePLtEh/J4 Yd2kYRyuqN788oEdSTZIKprA6lHUCiCmeuqCb0yEDsxJcCVX4GmDok5KMHm/E2bgjpRjVRxZ mrnLqTSwojt0LXg61vv8dNF8QD4sngPXqhmKQ7yp5O6S8ygn4lIPaUGOl5cgX1HsB3Q9Pfv3sg4A==&quot; is not a valid receipt handle.
```

Try #2
URL Encode the Receipt Handle:

```
Action=DeleteMessage&ReceiptHandle=AQEBjiliZegyBS%2FZO9wta%2Ba%2FheA%2FtSx%2Ff6tLFqfH38jEZ2r9zguHAljXhG%2FB8tXaM%2BS6MKs%2FXGyZ206S3NC2V38CUKLO%2BsPF0mfP47wqu7%2BnAIwettlxTGQAYuCFqI1CYBYHXxgajB1UEiFz8Kc6v8SlWs%2FVPLX%2BIWjckoQOtMRl977sxM5pCLhMNvIwh1RYFvybM0D0WEbJEuYb9JU3DZuRZg%2FK5rjvNooPqER4FR1JJxpZiJ0tu6481CyePLtEh%2FJ4%2BYd2kYRyuqN788oEdSTZIKprA6lHUCiCmeuqCb0yEDsxJcCVX4GmDok5KMHm%2FE2bgjpRjVRxZ%2BmrnLqTSwojt0LXg61vv8dNF8QD4sngPXqhmKQ7yp5O6S8ygn4lIPaUGOl5cgX1HsB3Q9Pfv3sg4A%3D%3D&Version=2012-11-05
```

Error response is:
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Does the receipt handle need to be encoded?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [SQS DeleteMessage docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html), your second attempt with URL encoding the receipt handle is correct.

It looks like you're having a problem with authentication & authorization - you need to sign your requests with auth params - this is what prevents (a) others from making unauthorized requests to your account's resources, and (b) others from intercepting and modifying (or replaying) your requests to your account's resources.

[This tutorial](https://blog.iron.io/amazon-sqs-simple-queue-service-overview-and-tutorial/) provides great details on this how to do this auth via postman:

> Postman makes it easy to setup all the necessary authorization using Collections. Configure the AWS authorization in the parent collection with the Access Key and Secret Access Key found in the AWS Console:  [image]
>   Then reference that authorization in each request:
>   [image]

For full information on how to construct the auth params more manually (which AWS API will do for you by the way), see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html